# Nextcloud : impossible to create or write in the data directory /media/pi/HCLOUD/nextcloudData/

Tags: raspberry-pi, nextcloud

I'm trying to build a Nextcloud server on my raspberry pi connected to an external disk. Installation worked. But during the setup I want to change the data directory (where all the files will be stored) to my external disk. 
But setup said: `impossible to create or write in the data directory /media/pi/HCLOUD/nextcloudData/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution !

First we need to **install nextcloud on the sd card** (like that : https://www.marksei.com/how-to-install-nextcloud-13-on-ubuntu/).

**If your disk is in ntfs format you really need to format it into ext4** - that gives to linux the possibilty of changing permissions on the disk.

Then **mount it** on this folder : /var/nextcloud and to **move the data repo** on the external HDD we need to follow this tutorial (step : moving nextcloud data folder): https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-nextcloud-server/

Answer (score 0):

try doing `sudo chown pi:www-data /media/pi/HCLOUD/nextcloudData/` and then change the data dir.

Comment: it said : chown: operation not permitted

Comment: did you use `sudo`

Comment: I think I founded where is the issue. This hard Disk is FAT one so I need to mount it with the right permissions (to allow data-www to write and read). Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: can you do this on the hard disk itself (change the permissions of the hard drive folder)